# Remove class= attribute

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I'm using simple xml library: http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php

I have a problem with @ElementList annotation: if I use this annotation like this:

```
@ElementList
protected List<Element> elements;
```

My XML file has one more attribute:

```
<elements class="java.util.ArrayList">
```

how to remove the attribute `class="....."` ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `class` Attribute tells Simple which implementation of `List` you use. If it's missing, Simple will look for a proper class itself.

One solution is to use `ArrayList` instead of `List`:

```
@ElementList
protected ArrayList<Element> elements;
```

Now Simple wont add the class-Attribute.

Another way:

```
@Path("elements")
@ElementList(inline=true)
protected List<Element> elements;
```

This inlines your List (no *elements*-Tag is used) but puts it into a "new" *elements*-Tag

Comment: Thanks I user ArrayList and it disappeared! :D