# Element name is already used simple framework

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

I'm parsing a xml into an object using Simple Framework.
The problem is that the xml has elements with the same name but in different paths.

XML:

```
<prestashop>
 <products>
   <product>
    <name>
       <language id="1"> name </language>
    </name>
    <description>
      <language id="1"> description </language>
    </description>
    <description_short>
      <language id="1"> desc </language>
    </description_short>
  </product>
 </products>
</prestashop>
```

my class is mapped like this:

```
@Root(name="prestashop")
public class Product{
    @Element(name="language")
    @Path("products/product/description_short[1]")
    private String shortDesc;

    @Element(name="language")
    @Path("products/product/description[1]")
    private String longDesc;

    @Element(name="language")
    @Path("products/product/name[1]")
    private String name;
}
```

But during the deserialization, it gives me the exception:

```
  org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: 
Element 'language' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=language, required=true, type=void) 
on field 'name' private java.lang.String model.Product.name at line 8
```

How can i map tags with the same name but in different paths?

if I serialize the product object it gives me the correct XML structure:

```
<prestashop xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <products>
       <product>
          <description_short>
             <language>short</language>
          </description_short>
          <id_default_image href="path"/>
          <description>
             <language>long</language>
          </description>
          <name>
             <language>aaa</language>
          </name>
          <price>10.0</price>
          <id>1</id>
       </product>
    </products>
 </prestashop>
```

Im deserializing like this:

```
product = new Product();
InputStream in = res.getResponse();
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
serializer.read(product, in,false);
```

Comment: The XML you provided in no way matches the annotations, provide the full XML and class definition for a sensible answer.

Comment: Maybe its better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example how to map class:

**(Example-) Class:**

```
@Root(name = "product")
public class Product
{
    @Path(value = "name")
    @Element(name = "language")
    private String name;

    @Path(value = "description")
    @Element(name = "language")
    private String description;

    @Path(value = "description_short")
    @Element(name = "language")
    private String desc;


    // ...

    /* For testing only */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Product{" + "name=" + name + ", description=" + description + ", desc=" + desc + '}';
    }
}
```

*(I don't have the full implementation but i hope my example is similar)*

**Input Xml:**

```
<product>
    <name>
        <language id="1"> name </language>
    </name>
    <description>
        <language id="1"> description </language>
    </description>
    <description_short>
        <language id="1"> desc </language>
    </description_short>
</product>
```

*Note the `<product> </product>` tag and the `"` for `id`-attribute (without them it can fail)*

**Test-Code:**

```
final File f = new File("test.xml"); // Input file

Serializer ser = new Persister();
Product p = ser.read(Product.class, f); // deserialize the class


System.out.println(p); // output - thats why i've implemented the 'toString()' method
```

**Output:**

```
Product{name= name , description= description , desc= desc }
```

*(Blanks are caused by xml)*

It looks like you want to serialize / deserialize a list so `products` should be a list (can be inlined) and `product` is the class from above.

---

---

## Edit:

**`Product` class:**

```
@Root(name = "product")
public class Product
{
    @Path(value = "name")
    @Element(name = "language")
    private String name;

    @Path(value = "description")
    @Element(name = "language")
    private String description;

    @Path(value = "description_short")
    @Element(name = "language")
    private String desc;

    @Element(name = "id_default_image")
    private AttributedElement idDefaultImage;

    @Element(name = "price")
    private double price;

    @Element(name = "id")
    private int id;



    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Product{" + "name=" + name + ", description=" + description 
                + ", desc=" + desc + ", idDefaultImage=" + idDefaultImage 
                + ", price=" + price + ", id=" + id + '}';
    }



    @Root(name = "AttributedElement")
    static class AttributedElement
    {
        @Attribute(name = "href")
        private String value;


        public AttributedElement(String value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        private AttributedElement()
        {
            /* Empty constructor required here */
        }


        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

}
```

***Note:*** I used that inner class as helper to get proper xml structure for the image element.

Now, next there's a class that wraps around the `Product`. I implemted this as a map, hoewever, if there's only one product you can use a simple class instead the list.

**`Prestashop` class:**

```
@Root(name = "prestashop")
public class Prestashop
{
    @ElementList(name = "products", empty = false, required = true)
    private ArrayList<Product> products;


    public Prestashop()
    {
        this.products = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    /* Some list methods */

    public void add(Product p)
    {
        products.add(p);
    }

    public Product get(int index)
    {
        return products.get(index);
    }

    public Product first()
    {
        return products.get(0);
    }

}
```

***Note:*** For an explanation why i don't use `List<Product>` here, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113025/remove-class-attribute/12145092#12145092).

**Test-Code:**

```
Serializer ser = new Persister();

Prestashop shop = ser.read(Prestashop.class, f);
System.out.println(shop.first());
```

**Input Xml:**

```
<prestashop xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <products>
       <product>
          <description_short>
             <language>short</language>
          </description_short>
          <id_default_image href="path"/>
          <description>
             <language>long</language>
          </description>
          <name>
             <language>aaa</language>
          </name>
          <price>10.0</price>
          <id>1</id>
       </product>
    </products>
 </prestashop>
```

*(2nd one of your question)*

And last ...

**Output:**

```
Product{name=aaa, description=long, desc=short, idDefaultImage=path, price=10.0, id=1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didnt work... it keeps giving the same error. The error is only given in the reading, if i write the xml structure is build correctly(see editted post). I cant find a way to make it work, is there any way around?

Comment: I see; please see my *edit* for a 2nd try and tell me your result :-)

Comment: @ollo Care to take a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999265/parsing-xml-feed-die-with-element-is-already-used