# Filter a list before serialization using SimpleXml

Tags: java, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I am trying to serialize a `parent` which contains a list of `child`s. These `child`s have an `activated` boolean field, and I want that the resulting XML contains only the `child`s wich an `activated` attribute set to `true`

I could do this by copying the `parent` object and filtering the `child`s in the process (and I may do this at the end) but I am wondering if it is possible to customize SimpleXML to have the same result.

**EDIT**

I used the response given by ollo. I just changed the `Converter` implementation for using the original annotations of the child classes.

#### The new `Converter` implementation:

```
public class ChildConverter implements Converter<Child>
{
    @Override
    public Child read(InputNode node) throws Exception
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }


    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, Child value) throws Exception
    {
        if( value.isActived() == true ) // Check if 'activated' flag is set
        {
            // Set valus of the child
            //We don't use an annotation strategy for this persister to avoid
            //a recursive call to this method.
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();
            serializer.write(value, node);
        }
        else
        {
            node.remove(); // Remove the node since we don't need it
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more informations (code, expected XML etc.) would be helpful ...

But here's an example how you can do this:

The key feature is implementing a [`Converter`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html), where you can customize how objects are serialized / deserialized. In the following code I implement a `Converter` for the `Child` class, however it's possible to implement it for the `Parent` class instead too.

#### The `Child` class:

```
@Root(name = "child")
@Convert(value = ChildConverter.class) // Set the Converter
public class Child
{
    private boolean actived;
    @Element(name = "value", required = true)
    private String value;
    @Element(name = "value2", required = true)
    private int secondValue;


    public Child(boolean actived, String value, int secondValue)
    {
        this.actived = actived;
        this.value = value;
        this.secondValue = secondValue;
    }



    public boolean isActived()
    {
        return actived;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public int getSecondValue()
    {
        return secondValue;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Beside the `activated` flag this class has two other members to show how do serialize them.

#### The `Parent` class:

```
@Root(name = "parent")
public class Parent
{
    @ElementList(name = "childs", required = true)
    private List<Child> childs;


    public Parent()
    {
        this.childs = new ArrayList<>();
    }



    public void addChild(Child child)
    {
        childs.add(child);
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### The `Converter` implementation:

```
public class ChildConverter implements Converter<Child>
{
    @Override
    public Child read(InputNode node) throws Exception
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }


    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, Child value) throws Exception
    {
        if( value.isActived() == true ) // Check if 'activated' flag is set
        {
            // Set valus of the child
            node.setValue(value.getValue());
            node.setAttribute("secondValue", String.valueOf(value.getSecondValue()));
        }
        else
        {
            node.remove(); // Remove the node since we don't need it
        }
    }

}
```

The implementation is not very complex so far. First we check if `activated` is set. If yes we fill the objects value into the node, if it's not set we remove the node (else you'll get a `<child />` in your XML).

#### How to use:

```
// Some test data
Parent p = new Parent();
p.addChild(new Child(true, "a", 1));
p.addChild(new Child(true, "b", 2));
p.addChild(new Child(false, "c", 3)); // "disabled"
p.addChild(new Child(true, "d", 4));
p.addChild(new Child(false, "e", 5)); // "disabled"
p.addChild(new Child(false, "f", 6)); // "disabled"


final File f = new File("test.xml");

Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy()); // Don't forget 'AnnotationStrategy'!
ser.write(p, f); // Serialize to a file or whatever you need
```

And finally ...

#### The XML output:

```xml
<parent>
   <childs class="java.util.ArrayList">
      <child secondValue="1">a</child>
      <child secondValue="2">b</child>
      <child secondValue="4">d</child>
   </childs>
</parent>
```

There are only `child` elements for object where `activated` was `true`, those with `false` are skipped.

***Note:*** If you want to remove `class="java.util.ArrayList"` please see here: [Remove class= attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113025/remove-class-attribute/12145092#12145092)

Comment: Thanks for your response, and sorry for the lack of code example in my question. But it seems you grasped the problem anyway :). I will test this solution in a few hour but I think that is the right answer.

Comment: Feel free to post any problems ;-)

Comment: Okay, it's working like a charm, but I have an additional question : In the write method, do I have a way to serialize the Child instance to a node using the annotations put on it ? Because, if I understand correctly, the two Element annotation on the value and secondValue fields of the Child class are note used.

Comment: Okay found it. Check my edition in the question if your interested.