# Removing XML Java class attribute from SimpleXML code

Tags: java, xml, web-services, simple-framework

I am using SimpleXML to generate XML in a web service. But what I find with SimplexML is that the resulting code includes an attribute containing the underlying Java class type of the objects being represented.

So if I am using a Java ArrayList of a class of mine which is stored in the `recentVisualisation` element below, I get:

```
<User_Recent_Visualisations>
  <userNo>025347_17042011_1303046799093</userNo>
  <recentVisualisations class="java.util.ArrayList">
     <recent_Visualisation recentVisNo="9" recentVisName="fred">
        <createdDateTime>2013-06-28T14:09:17</createdDateTime>
    </recent_Visualisation>
  ...
</User_Recent_Visualisations>
```

Does anyone know if the attribute `class="java.util.ArrayList">` can be suppressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code if you are using `List<Type> recentVisualisations` for your items, Change it to `ArrayList<Type> recentVisualisations` (of course make sure this is what you want). The class attribute tells you what implementation of List is being used

**UPDATE**

You can also make it inline like mentioned here: [Remove class= attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113025/remove-class-attribute)

Basically

```
@Path("recentVisualisations")
@VisualisationList(inline=true)
<Access-Specifier>List<Type> recentVisualisations;
```

Comment: But can the attribute be removed?

Comment: Try either the first or the second above and the attribute should disappear

Comment: Many thanks. The attribute is gone.