# Java SimpleXML populates inner object with class attribute

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I am new to Simple XML, but I have encountered problem with population of unwanted objects in inner elements.

The actual problem is that I want to have this hierarchy:

```
<Request>
    <SpecificRequest>
         <UniqueID></UniqueID>
             or
         <Password></Password>
    </SpecificRequest>
</Request>
```

But have this:

```
<Request>
     <SpecificRequest>
        <mData class="com.example.package.UIDData">
           <UniqueID>6252859A</UniqueID>
        </mData>
     </SpecificRequest >
</Request>
```

Classes look like this:

Root request object:

```
@Root(name = "Request")
public class Request {
    @Element(name = "SpecificRequest")
    private SpecificRequest mSpecificRequest;

    public Request(SpecificRequest specificRequest) {
        mSpecificRequest = specificRequest;
    }
}
```

Specific request object:

```
public class SpecificRequest {
    private Data mData;

    public SpecificRequest(Data data) {
        mData = data;
    }
}
```

Generic data class:

```
public abstract class Data {
    private Type mType = Type.None;

    protected Data(Type type) {
        mType = type;
    }

    // other abstract stuff
}
```

And specific data class:

```
public class UIDData extends Data {
    @Element(name = "UniqueID")
    private String mUID;

    public UIDData(String UID) {
        super(Type.UID);
        mUID = UID;
    }
}
```

P.S. This is not duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391184/removing-xml-java-class-attribute-from-simplexml-code) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113025/remove-class-attribute).

Answer (score 1):

Add UIDData.class as type in SimpleXml @Element annotation

```
public class TestClass {

private String getXmlBody(Object o, Matcher matcher) throws Exception {
        Format format = new Format(4, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
        Serializer serializer = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy(), matcher, format);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        serializer.write(o, writer);
        writer.write('\n');
        return writer.toString();
    }    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 Data data = new UIDData("some UUID value ");
 SpecificRequest specificRequest  =  new SpecificRequest(data);
 Request request = new Request(specificRequest);
 System.out.println(getXmlBody(request, new RegistryMatcher()));
        }
    }
    @Root(name = "Request")
    class Request {
        @Element(name = "SpecificRequest")
        private SpecificRequest mSpecificRequest;

        public Request(SpecificRequest specificRequest) {
            mSpecificRequest = specificRequest;
        }
    }
    class SpecificRequest {
     @Element(type = UIDData.class)
        private Data mData;

        public SpecificRequest(Data data) {
            mData = data;
        }
    }

    abstract class Data {
        private String mType = "";

        protected Data(String type) {
            mType = type;
        }

        // other abstract stuff
    }

    class UIDData extends Data {
        @Element(name = "UniqueID")
        private String mUID;

        public UIDData(String UID) {
            super("UID");
            mUID = UID;
        }
    }
```