# Sending list values with retrofit and simplexml cause render class="java.util.ArrayList"

Tags: android, retrofit, simple-framework

i would send with retrofit this type of xml structure:

```
...<Responses>
<Response>
  <QuestionID>ApplicantName</QuestionID>
  <ResponseText>Judy JobSeeker</ResponseText>
</Response>
<Response>
  <QuestionID>ApplicantEmail</QuestionID>
  <ResponseText>Judy.JobSeeker@bogusemail.com</ResponseText>
</Response>...
```

My entity has this structure:

```
@Root(name = "RequestApplication") public class CRequestApplication {
@Element(name = "DeveloperKey")
public String DeveloperKey;

@Element(name = "JobDID")
public String JobDID;

@Element(name = "Test")
public boolean Test;

@Element(name = "Resume")
public CResume Resume;

@ElementList(name = "Responses")
public List<CResponse> Responses;
```

}

but when i post the request the soap message sent is:

```
<Responses class="java.util.ArrayList">
<Response>
<QuestionID>ApplicantName</QuestionID>
<ResponseText>Alfredo De Vito</ResponseText>
</Response>
<Response>
<QuestionID>ApplicantEmail</QuestionID>
<ResponseText>alfdev@gmail.com</ResponseText>
</Response>
</Responses>
```

the issue is the responses'attribute 'class="java.util.ArrayList"' that couse this server error message: "The 'class' attribute is not declared."

Any idea to how can i avoid to render this class="..." attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `class=...` as described here: [Remove class= attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113025/remove-class-attribute/12145092#12145092)

Use the first solution mentioned there (if possible).